# How to make node with Mobile app

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, how can I make an android or ios app as a node in ros, which can subscribe and publish stuffs? Any good tutorial about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268977/how-to-make-node-with-mobile-app/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-08-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BryanYM](https://answers.ros.org/users/47439/bryanym/) on 2019-10-17**:
Hi, have you found any good stuff that helps to make ios app? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@rozoalex try http://wiki.ros.org/android and http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava.

This will link you to the rosjava organization: http://github.com/rosjava.

Currently, there is no iOS support that I am aware of.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0